# Statements that say in another way that "$S$ is an open set"

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that we speak about open sets in $\mathbb R^{n}$ and that they are defined in the usual way with the help of open balls.

I know that these statements are another way of saying that "$S$ is an open set":

> 1) The complement of $S$ is closed
>
> 2) $S ∩ ∂S = ∅$
>
> 3) each point $s \in S$ is an interior point

I would like to know are there any other widely (or not widely) known statements that *describe* open sets in another way, like the mentioned 1), 2), and 3)?

You can add more than one if you know about more than one.

Comment: Strictly speaking the notion of open set is a primitive concept of topology.  While any number of equivalent statements to "$S$ is an open set in topology $\tau$" can be adduced, the reality is you must give a topology $\tau$ that (by definition) determines which sets are open (and which are not).  It would greatly improve your Question if you tied the effort to adduce equivalent statements to some goal or purpose, thereby giving narrower context to what will strike many Readers as overly broad or pointless.

Answer (score 5):

- $S$ is a union of open balls.
- $S$ is a *countable* union of open balls.
- .. or of Cartesian products of open intervals.
- $S$ is $\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid f(x)>0 \}$ for some continuous function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$.
- $S$ is $\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid f(x)>0 \}$ for some $\mathcal C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$.
- $S$ is $\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid f(x)\ne 0 \}$ for some $\mathcal C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$.
- $S$ is $\{x\in\mathbb R^n \mid \varphi(x)\}$ where $\varphi$ is any logical formula built with $\lor$, $\land$ and strict inequalities $f(x)<g(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$.
- for every $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, if $A$ is sequentially compact, then $A\setminus S$ is sequentially compact too.